# for i in `ls |grep` question

Tags: unix, grep, tar

This is the code i'm using to untar a file grep on the contents of the files within the tar and then delete the untared files. I dont have enough space to untar all files at once.

the issue i'm having is with the **for f in `ls | grep -v *.gz** line this is supposed to find the files that have come out of the tar and can be identified by not having a .tar.gz extension but it doesnt seem to pick them up?

Any help would be much appreciated

M

```
for i in *.tar.gz; 
do echo $i >>outtput1; 
     tar -xvvzf $i; mv $i ./processed/; 
     for f in `ls | grep -v *.gz`;  ----- this is the line that isn't working
     do echo $f  >> outtput1; 
     grep 93149249194 $f >> 
     outtput1; grep 788 $f >> outtput1; 
     rm -f $f; 
     done; 
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `ls -1 | grep -v "\\.gz$"`.  The `-1` will make `ls` output one result per line.  I've also fixed your regex for you in a few ways.

Although a better way to solve this whole thing is with `find -exec`.

Comment: No need for -1. When you pipe ls output, normally the files are given one by one.

Comment: @thegeek: why, so they are.  Nifty.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to `ls | grep -v "*.gz"`, you have to quote `*.gz` because otherwise it will just glob the files in the working directory and grep them.

Answer (score 0):

Never use `ls` in scripts, and don't use `grep` to match file patterns. Use globbing and tests instead:

```
for f in *
do
    if [[ $f != *.gz ]]
    then
        ...
    fi
done
```